# Is there any series for $x^y$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I wonder if there is any kind of generic series expansion for:

$$x^y$$

Where $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$. And the serie uses integer powers and other functions.  Something like:

$$x^y = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{y^k\cdot f(k,x)}$$

where $f(k,x)$ is function of complex value.

Comment: Specifying a branch for $\log(x)$, we can write $$x^y=e^{\log(x)\,y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\log(x))^ny^n}{n!}$$

Comment: It can not be more exact to what I was looking for. If you want to add is the answer :-) Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifying a branch for the complex logarithm, $\log(x)$, and using $x^y=e^{\log(x)\,y}$, we have

$$x^y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\log(x))^n\,y^n}{n!}$$

And we are.done.